# Oracle (Amazon RDS) session hangs

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, oracle12c

I have a primary process and a mirror process. They both connect to same schema. Primary process execute dml queries while mirror do the fetching. Randomly primary process is hanged in an update query with following stack trace

```
#0  0x00007fceaffe170d in read () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fceb64c9150 in snttread () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#2  0x00007fceb48e7c75 in nttrd () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#3  0x00007fceb47c887a in nsprecv () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#4  0x00007fceb47d1bd5 in nsrdr () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#5  0x00007fceb5855282 in nsfull_pkt_rcv () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#6  0x00007fceb585b7af in nsfull_brc () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#7  0x00007fceb64bdaae in nsbrecv () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#8  0x00007fceb64b3b3e in nioqrc () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#9  0x00007fceb64c971d in ttcdrv () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#10 0x00007fceb64b8649 in nioqwa () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#11 0x00007fceb649a74c in upirtrc () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#12 0x00007fceb64a4f66 in kpurcsc () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#13 0x00007fceb649c042 in kpuexec () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
#14 0x00007fceb649b0f9 in OCIStmtExecute () from /app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
```

When examined in session level (v$sqltext, v$lock), mirror is in a blocking (block=1) call with a select statement, while primary is in waiting (block=0) state with an update statement to the same table. Can a select statement be in a blocking call ? What are the directions that i can investigate this further ?

Comment: A regular SELECT should never block an UPDATE - part of the whole "readers don't block writers" idea of multiversion concurrency control. How long do these hangs happen for? Is your statement using the FOR UPDATE clause? Is there something else happening in the transactions that's maybe not being committed?

Comment: DB Thread of the primary process keeps hanged until i kill the mirror. No, i am not using FOR UPDATE clause. Something else in the transactions is the suspicion. But i couldn't see it in the code.